# ¿Se debe escribir "Internet" con mayúscula inicial?

Tags: ortografía, vocabulario-técnico, informática, nombres-propios, uso-de-mayúsculas

La idea que yo tenía era que la palabra *Internet* se debía escribir con mayúscula al ser un nombre propio. El DPD [parece confirmar esto](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=Internet):

> Funciona a modo de nombre propio, por lo que, en el uso mayoritario de todo el ámbito hispánico, se escribe con mayúscula inicial y sin artículo.

Sin embargo, buscando la palabra en el DLE (que es posterior a la última edición del DPD), me encuentro con lo siguiente:

> **[internet](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LvskgUG)**
>
> Del ingl. *Internet*.
>   Escrito también con mayúscula inicial.
>
> 1. m. o f. Red informática mundial, descentralizada, formada por la conexión directa entre computadoras mediante un protocolo especial de comunicación.

En la definición parece intuirse que ambas formas son aceptadas. Así que ya por curiosidad, ¿cuál es la última recomendación de la RAE? ¿Escribirlo con mayúscula inicial o da exactamente igual?

Comment: Curioso. [Dice RAE en Twitter](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/651645636912267264): _«Internet», con mayúscula inicial como nombre propio de la red. Puede ir con minúscula si se refiere al servicio_. Interesante ese "puede ir", parece que no está del todo estandarizado. Sea como fuere, parece que la tendencia será cada vez más la de verlo como servicio y, por tanto, usar la minúscula.

Comment: Supongo que será como otras reglas para el [uso de mayúsculas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp), en concreto 4.11 donde se dice que "Las palabras Sol y Luna solo suelen escribirse con mayúscula inicial en textos científicos de temática astronómica, en los que designan los respectivos astros". Quizá depende de cómo nos estemos refiriendo a Internet. @fedorqui, deberías publicar una respuesta (formal) con ese contenido, pues esa parece ser la más reciente recomendación de la RAE (básicamente, distinguir si es nombre propio).

Answer (score 7):

Por regla general (esto me lo dijo un amigo corrector de textos para editoriales) se puede escribir de las dos maneras, pero no en los mismos contextos.

Se escribe "Internet" con mayúscula inicial cuando se usa como nombre propio. Por ejemplo, decir "La red Internet evolucionó de la red militar ARPANET", mientras que "internet" se refiere a la red en sí misma como servicio, como cuando dices, "Voy a hacer una búsqueda en internet".

De todos modos, ni los correctores de textos se ponen de acuerdo, y en mi caso he visto manuscritos míos en los que el corrector me lo ha puesto siempre con mayúscula inicial y otros casos en los que otro corrector distinguía entre el uso como nombre propio, y las referencias al servicio en sí mismo.

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer*: lo siguiente es mi opinión como ingeniero de telecomunicaciones. Puede que en entornos, no sé... bursátiles o algo así, "Internet" tenga otro sentido.

---

Internet es el nombre de una red concreta. La mayor del mundo, seguramente; pero no la única. Existen redes locales, redes virtuales de empresas, conexiones punto a punto, redes anónimas como Freenet o Tor... Ninguna de las cuales es a lo que nos referimos cuando decimos "voy a conectarme a Internet".
Por tanto, en el 99,99% de los casos, cuando hablamos de Internet nos estamos refiriendo a la red por su nombre, y por tanto debe ir en mayúscula.

No se me ocurre ninguna situación en que pueda escribirse en minúscula como "servicio": "*No va Internet*"; "*Este juego requiere acceso a Internet*", "*Vodafónica es un proveedor de servicios de Internet*"... Siempre en mayúscula.

Afinando mucho, *podría* cuadrar el uso en minúscula (aunque yo lo pondría en mayúscula igualmente) en un contexto muy técnico como "*Este es el* router *que da salida a internet*": donde estamos hablando de la infraestructura de red de, por ejemplo, una oficina; y donde por "internet" nos estamos refiriendo en realidad a cualquier red que no sea la red interna. Y con todo, lo correcto ahí sería decir "salida al exterior" o "salida a la red externa".

Nota curiosa: Hasta el corrector ortográfico del navegador me dice que los "internet" del anterior párrafo deberían ir con mayúscula.

Comment: Hombre, tu opinión como ingeniero de telecomunicaciones tiene más peso que la un corredor de bolsa -siguiendo con tu ejemplo- en este tema en concreto, se te suponen conocimientos sobre redes. Vale que a veces los textos técnicos tienen sus propias características que no siempre comparten con los textos comunes pero la opinión de un experto sobre un término es importante para entender de qué estamos hablando.